# Difference between capturing return value by `const auto&` and `auto`

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, rvalue-reference

I've seen code like `const auto& now = time(nullptr);`

I think the purpose of assigning the rvalue returned by `time` is to extend the return value's lifetime, as explained in the [GotW post](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/). But why not use `const auto now = time(nullptr)`?

Why do we want to extend the lifetime of the return value here? and is there any performance difference?

Comment: Not for this case, but `auto` does not infer references, so, it may just be a "good habit", for when you return referenced objects, and want to avoid a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the shown example, there is no reason to use a reference. The behavior of the snippet is identical with or without it.

In general, it's a good idea to use a reference to avoid incurring needless copies, so there's no harm in getting into the habit of using references, even if it doesn't make a difference in some cases.

I'd suggest writing `const` on the east though. This is just a preference, and definitely doesn't change the meaning of the code, but it's more consistent. I would write it as:

```
auto const & now = time(nullptr);
```

Comment: I know in C++17 copy elision is mandatory so, if I understand it correctly, `auto const x = rvalue;` should always avoid the copy/move in C++17; however, doesn't this mean that the OP could meet a strange C++14-compliant compiler which makes the copy/move (even in the shown example)?

Comment: @Enlico If I remove `const` and use `auto x = rvalue`, will the copy elision work here?

Comment: @Enlico I can't imagine any compiler not generating the same assembly in either case. In the OP's code, `auto` is a `time_t` which is probably something like an `int`, so it's essentially the same as the difference between `auto const & x = 42;`, and `auto const x = 42;`, which is nothing. Also, copy elision applies to *returning* from a function, so I don't think it matters at all here.

Comment: @llxxee The `const` doesn't make a difference when it's `auto const x = rvalue` vs `auto x = rvalue;`. It only affects whether `x` can be modified.

Comment: @cigien, [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) for _copy elision_ has a bullet point for `return` and another for _initialization_.

Comment: @Enlico I could be wrong, but I think that only applies to class types. On the other hand, `std::time_t` is not *required* to be a non-class type, so yeah, I guess one could write code where there is some observable difference between the 2 versions. It would still only work for one's own type though, so it wouldn't apply to the OP's case.

Comment: @cigien, thanks for the clarification. Given the title of the question I thought the OP was referring to `auto const& x = rvalue;` vs `auto const x = rvalue;` for general types, including class types. Apparently I was wrong, as your answer is accepted.